# Browser makes OPTIONS request to django for CORS request, but no POST

Tags: django, cors, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to submit a form from a react application, via post, to a django server on a different origin.

The browser sends an OPTIONS request, which the cors middleware on the server responds to with a 200, and the following information:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 16:34:38 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Connection: keep-alive
```

But the browser never subsequently makes a POST request. It shows no errors in the console...

Comment: So that’s a valid preflight response and the preflight isn’t failing (if it were failing, the browser would be logging a specific error saying so) — and given that, there’s nothing blocking the browser from making the POST request from your code. So I have no idea why the browser isn’t doing that. Have you tried in a different browser, and do you see the same behavior in that other browser? Have you tried changing (temporarily, just for testing) the characteristics of the request (e.g., request headers) such that it doesn’t trigger a preflight and in that case does the POST happen as expected?

Comment: How did you conclude that the browser doesn’t make the POST request? If you open the Network pane in devtools and reload does the POST request not show up there after the OPTIONS request?

Comment: @sideshowbarker The django dev server lists all requests that it receives. It receives the OPTIONS, but no subsequent POST. If I switch the mode to 'no-cors', the server does indeed receive a POST request.

Comment: OK I understand that’s what you’re seeing from the server side. But what do you see on the client side in the Network tab in browser devtools? It’s imaginable that the browser is actually making the POST request, but that it’s subsequently getting canceled, for example. And also like I said, have you tried it in any other browsers and do you see the same behavior there?

Comment: @sideshowbarker Sorry for the delay. There is now an error:
`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. According to the devtools, there is no POST request made... Different browsers do the same

Comment: @sideshowbarker This now works locally, but the exact same code doesn't work when the request goes through nginx as a proxy. Could it be affecting the request?

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @Alex I have the exact same issue and it is driving me crazy, please tell me what was the solution for you

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `django-cors-headers` (https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) app and just add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to you django settings file. It is the simplest way to fix you issue and this app gives you a lot of CORS customization options.

Or you can write custom middleware and add CORS headers for each response.

Otherwise you could add CORS headers config to you web-server (nginx, apache, etc.).

Comment: I've already done that, that is what is responding to the initial OPTIONS request

Comment: Do you use any browser extensions for CORS? If so, disable them.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that

Comment: Nevertheless, I think the issue is on clent side. You can send request with Postman or CURL and watch response headers.

Answer (score 1):

go to inspect element for request response, and check if any "headers are not allowed" message there.

If so, add that header to CORS_ALLOW_HEADER = ['that-header'] in django settings.py

In my case, cache-control header was not allowed. So I added it, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you have to add `Cache-Control` to `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` to get it to work correctly. Some browsers don't handle setting it to '*'. Here's my setup:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
    "cache-control",
    "pragma",
]
```